# How to build bundled scripts from a monolithic Node TypeScript repository?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, build, compilation

I have a monolithic Node TypeScript project. Within this project, there's a scripts folder containing multiple files. Each file is intended to act as a separate service/script and these files share common libraries, methods, and classes.

*For example, I have a `HttpRequest` class that is used across multiple files and internally utilizes the `axios` library.*

Here's my challenge: I want to maintain the monolithic structure during development to minimize code redundancy. However, when I compile the project to a `"/dist"` folder, I'd like each file in the scripts folder to become a standalone, bundled JavaScript file that can be executed independently. Essentially, each built file should contain everything it needs to run on its own.

I've tried using Webpack, but it seems either too complex or not suited for this specific requirement. Is there a simpler or better way to achieve this?

Example folder structure:

```
> scripts/
  -------->test1.ts
  -------->test2.ts
  -------->test3.ts
> shared/
  -------->shared1.ts
  -------->shared2.ts
  -------->httpRequestAgnostic.ts
```

Thank you.

`@edit`

This was my test with webpack:

```js
import path from "path";
import TsconfigPathsPlugin from "tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin";
import TerserPlugin from "terser-webpack-plugin";

export default {
  mode: "production",
  target: "node",
  entry: {
    test1: "./src/scripts/test1.ts",
    test2: "./src/scripts/test2.ts",
    test3: "./src/scripts/test3.ts",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "ts-loader",
            options: {
              transpileOnly: true,
            },
          },
        ],

        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
    plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin({ configFile: "./tsconfig.json" })],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        terserOptions: {
          format: {
            comments: false,
          },
        },
        extractComments: false,
      }),
    ],
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true,
  },
  output: {
    module: true,
    filename: "[name].js",
    path: path.resolve("microservices"),
    library: {
      type: "module",
    },
    chunkFormat: "module",
    clean: true,
  },
};
```

Comment: Do you mean you want your dist scripts to **not** import each other?

Comment: I'm not sure I got your question right. I simply want in the `dist` all the scripts that are currently in the `scripts` folder each one bundled in one file.
So I will have for example `dist/test1.js` that needs to have inside everything needed for that script (all the shared scripts it uses). In this way I will be able to take each "`test script`" and run it independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I'd post an alternative viewpoint that suggests some other techniques. Feel free to ignore if you disagree with my opinions.

**BUNDLING**

This is a best practice for web apps, to reduce download sizes. It reduces many source files to a single minified one.

**READABILITY**

Doing so reduces readability of production code though. In your case you have a kind of microservice, where the compiled code should stay close to the original code.

**TROUBLESHOOTING**

It is worth considering how you can resolve incidents based on stack traces. If you bundle you need to keep source maps to get back to the original code:

[image]

**DEPLOYMENT**

A better packaging option might be a single process deployed to a server or a docker image, like [this example of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.nodejs/blob/master/deployment/kubernetes/Dockerfile) to deploy a single node app:

```
CMD ["node", "dist/app.js"]
```

The main thread might use [node-cron](https://github.com/node-cron/node-cron) or be callable as a REST API.

**OPERATIONS**

There are various options here. By default the API can just run tasks using its event loop. If this does not perform well enough, then there are Node.js options for [worker threads](https://medium.com/@Trott/using-worker-threads-in-node-js-80494136dbb6) or [child processes](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.serverless/blob/master/test/utils/lambdaChildProcess.ts).

So a single unit of deployment with multiple operations feels like it will give you the best options.

Comment: I like your approach. But in this way, if I have inside the `scripts` folder like 20 scripts.. I will have to deploy 20 dockers with, inside, the same code for each one. 
But for sure you said something really useful: I will not be able to track down a problem if I will not have the map files

Comment: Feels like your scripts could perhaps be invoked. as REST API endpoints. From your description it does sound a little like a Node.js microservice.

Comment: mmh yes and no. The problem is that all the scripts needs to run together or cron based. With REST API, I should have one node process running which calls each function of each script. That is the problem of node.. single process. That's why I wanted to have a sort of microservice

Comment: Node can spin up child processes when needed - so perhaps a single process that does that - I updated my answer - interesting discussion ...

Comment: so from my understanding, you are saying that I could have in a docker, a simple (just an example) express/fastify node api server, and calling a route, it will spawn a child process that will run another docker image? Just to understand if I got it.. If it's in this way, isn't dangerous? is it pretty-coding? Curiosity, unfortunately I'm not a senior BE dev

Comment: I would favour a single deployment rather than many, though of course you can split it in future. This could be to docker or a server. See the notes I added on operations - you have some choices there.

Comment: Thank you Gary, I really appreciate! This is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

yes, there is a similar way to achieve this without using Webpack. so then you can you rollup to fix this issue. Rollup is js bundler designed to be more lightweight and easy to use rather than Webpack.

if you need to use rollup ,you will need to create a rollup config file as well. so then this file will tell rollup how to bundle your code.

Here is the sample `rollup.config.js` file:

```
Import typescript from "rollup-plugin-typescript";

export default [
  {

    input : "./script/test1.ts",
    output: {
        file: "./dist/bundle1.js",
            format: "esm", // or "cjs"
    },
    plugin: [typescript()],
  },
  {
    input: 'scripts/test2.ts',
    output: {
      file: 'dist/bundle12.js',
      format: 'esm',
    },
    plugins: [typescript()],
  },
  {
    input: 'scripts/test3.ts',
    output: {
      file: 'dist/bundle13.js',
      format: 'esm',
    },
    plugins: [typescript()],
  }
];
```

to compile your code,use that command,

```
npx rollup -c
```

It will compile your code for each entry point `(test1.ts, test2.ts, test3.ts)` and create bundled file into its corresponding output `(dist/test1.js, dist/test2.js, dist/test3.js)` in `dist` folder.

Comment: let me test it later today, and if it works I will accept and give you the bounty

Comment: Nope, I tested yesterday and today but nope, it's not working.
I created a paste to see my test if you want to comment. https://pastebin.com/y0S0HH2H (pwd: `stackoverflow`)

Answer (score 0):

I would create a `webpack.config.js` file at the root of your project and inside write this:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

// Set multiple entry points
const entries = {};
fs.readdirSync('./scripts').forEach(file => {
  if (file.match(/\.ts$/)) {
    const filename = file.replace(/\.ts$/, '');
    entries[filename] = `./scripts/${file}`;
  }
});

module.exports = {
  entry: entries,
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

This will read all `.ts` files in scripts folder and use them as entry points for Webpack. Each entry point is bundled into single `.js` file in the `dist` folder (including all dependencies).

Then run Webpack to generate the bundled files:

```
npx webpack --config webpack.config.js
```

After that you will see bundled `.js` files in `dist` folder. Each of these files will be a standalone script that includes all its dependencies and you can run each script independently.

You can run `test2.js` like this:

```
node dist/test2.js
```

Comment: I already tried with Webpack and it wasn't working as expected. 
You can see the code I used to try webpack above (i edited my question adding that to the bottom). Let me know if you think I made something wrong with webpack.